# Sort a Map according to some rules

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, alphabetical

I have a map that i want to sort its contents according to some rules :

> 1. Sort the map Alphabetically (From A to Z) according to its Values and not its Keys.
> 2. Ignore the Case Sensitivity of the Values while sorting them.
> 3. Put duplicate words into consideration(Words having exact letters Spelling & Case).
> 4. Sort the Alpha numeric words right(**Cbc2ee** should appear before **Cbc100ee**).
> 5. Handle non English words(**área** should appear in the words starting with "a" letter but actually it appears after words starting with "z" letter, considering á another letter).

I think what i want is all logical. I was able to accomplish points 1, 2 & 3 through this code :

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> LinkedHashMap<K, V> sortMapByValues( Map<K, V> map ) {
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
            @Override 
            public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> e1, Map.Entry<K, V> e2 ) {
                String a = (String)e1.getValue();
                String b = (String)e2.getValue();

                int diff = a.compareToIgnoreCase( b );

                if (diff == 0) 
                    diff = a.compareTo(b);  

                return diff != 0 ? diff : 1;  // Special fix to preserve words with similar spelling.
            }
        }
    );

    sortedEntries.addAll( map.entrySet() );

    LinkedHashMap<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();

    for( Map.Entry<K, V> sortedEntry : sortedEntries )
        sortedMap.put( sortedEntry.getKey(), sortedEntry.getValue() );

    return sortedMap;
}
```

Point (4) i have found a script for it but i could not merge it with my code :
http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Point (5) also i have found a script for it but i could not merge it with my code :
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=207

As these points will affect the compare(...) method.
**Any one can help me with that ?**

Comment: Seems to me that actually solving 4 and 5 would solve 1, 2, 3 instead. The way to do it would be to use the script from 4, and then replace the sorting mechanism with the second example from 5.

Comment: The code you found for Point (4) is right on the money, and the code you found for Point (5) is also right on the money. If you cannot merge them into your code, then you need to better familiarize yourself with the Java language. Stack Overflow is intended for asking questions about specific things and having them answered; it is not intended for asking people to write your code for you.

Comment: Of course, you can always have the reputation whores write your code for you, by enticing them with plentiful bounty.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points...

The method signature should be:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> sortMapByValues(Map<K, V> map)
```

Note:
- Removal of the bound to `Comparable`, because you are comparing the `toString()` of the map values, not the values themselves
- Specification of the abstract type `Map<...>`, rather than the concrete `LinkedHashMap`, as per good design guidelines
- `static` because it doesn't change state - it's "just code"

Now then, your solution is very good. It just needs a little more code to make those extra points to happen.

Here's some code that should do what you want:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> sortMapByValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> e1, Map.Entry<K, V> e2) {
            String aRaw = e1.getValue().toString();
            String bRaw = e2.getValue().toString();
            String a = standardize(aRaw);
            String b = standardize(bRaw);

            // Check for hex
            try
            {
                Integer ai = Integer.parseInt(a, 16);
                Integer bi = Integer.parseInt(b, 16);
                int diff = ai.compareTo(bi);
                if (diff != 0)
                    return diff;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ignore)
            {
            }

            int diff = a.compareTo(b);
            if (diff != 0)
                return diff;
            return aRaw.compareTo(bRaw);
        }

        /** This method removes all accent (diacritic) marks and changes to lower case */
        String standardize(String input) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                char c = input.charAt(i);
                sb.append(Normalizer.normalize(c + "", Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""));
            }
            return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
        }
    });

    // The rest is your code left as it was, cos it's fine
    sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());

    LinkedHashMap<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();

    for (Map.Entry<K, V> sortedEntry : sortedEntries)
        sortedMap.put(sortedEntry.getKey(), sortedEntry.getValue());

    return sortedMap;
}
```

Here's the test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("a", "CC96");
    map.put("b", "CC97");
    map.put("c", "CC102");
    map.put("d", "CC103");
    map.put("e", "aabbcc");
    map.put("f", "aabbCC");
    map.put("g", "atabends");
    map.put("h", "aaBBcc");
    map.put("i", "AABBcc");
    map.put("j", "aabbcc");
    map.put("k", "Cc102");
    map.put("l", "baldmöglichst");
    map.put("m", "bar");
    map.put("n", "barfuss");
    map.put("o", "barfuß");
    map.put("p", "spätabends");
    map.put("q", "ätabends");
    map.put("r", "azebra");

    System.out.println(sortMapByValues(map).toString()
        .replaceAll(", ", "\r").replaceAll("(\\{|\\})", ""));
}
```

Output:

```
a=CC96
b=CC97
c=CC102
k=Cc102
d=CC103
i=AABBcc
h=aaBBcc
f=aabbCC
e=aabbcc
g=atabends
q=ätabends
r=azebra
l=baldmöglichst
m=bar
n=barfuss
o=barfuß
p=spätabends
```

Comment: @Bohemain: Thanks for the nice solution, especially for the standardize(...) method. It is only missing handling duplicate words, like (CC102, Cc102, aaBBcc, AABBcc, aabbcc). The script will only take one instance of the duplicated word & ignore the others. Even if you take the words case sensitivity into consideration, the words sorting may appear wrong. Here is a complete list of words i have tested: (CC96, CC97, CC102, CC103, aabbcc, aabbCC, atabends, aaBBcc, AABBcc, aabbcc, Cc102, baldmöglichst, bar, barfuss, barfuß, spätabends, ätabends, azebra)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "ignoring". Maps have keys and values - what exactly are the keys and values you are putting into the map being passed to the `sortMapByValues` method?

Comment: @Bohemain: The keys may be any unique id, so the map would be: [a: CC96, b: CC97, c: CC102, d: CC103, e: aabbcc, f: aabbCC, g: atabends, h: aaBBcc, i: AABBcc, j: aabbcc, k: Cc102, l: baldmöglichst, m: bar, n: barfuss, o: barfuß, p: spätabends, q: ätabends, r: azebra]. Now if i sort this map's values using your code, it will result: [atabends, azebra, baldmöglichst, bar, barfuss, barfuß, CC96, CC97, CC102, CC103, aabbcc, spätabends].

Comment: OK. I found the problem, which was if the standardized values are the same, then compare the original values. This ensures the TreeSet considers the two values to be *different* and thus includes them. See edited answer for bug fix and test code that uses your data. Note that if two entries have the *exact same* value, only one will be retained. To fix this, return the comparison of the *key* if the raw *values* are the same.

Comment: @Bohemain: I think you have also removed the toLowerCase() from the standardize(...) method, right ? ... One thing remaining: The "C" words(Like: CC96) still appear in your result before the "A" words(Like: AABBcc), so they are not yet sorted Alphabetically(Rule 2).

Comment: toLowerCase() is still in there - check again the return statement. I interpreted rule 4 to override rule 2 - ie if it's a hex number, sort it as a number. If you want something else, code it. I have given you enough to modify it to your liking.

Comment: @Bohemain: Thanks a lot for your effort. I mixed your code with the AlphaNumberic script in my post for this to work. Now it sorts them as expected.